How do I git clone a tag with the same name as a branch?
This clones a branch or tag named goober.
% git clone --branch goober <repo> <directory>

If there's both a branch and a tag with that name, it clones the branch.  That disagrees with the pecking order listed near the beginning of gitrevisions, which prioritizes tags over branches, and there seems to be no way to clone the tag instead.  Cloning refs/tags/goober or tags/goober doesn't work either:  "Remote branch tags/goober not found in upstream origin".
How can I reliably clone a tag even in the face of this ambiguity?
Normally, this wouldn't be a problem, but I want a minimal clone, preferably blobless.  I know I can clone multiple ways and switch to the tag.

just checkout the tag, you got that too. --branch foo only sets what gets checked out initially.

Exactly. Just git clone and then checkout your tag.

I want a minimal clone, e.g., --depth=1, --filter=blob:none, etc.

git clone is convenience shorthand for (suitable args on) git init; cd; git remote add; git fetch, when there's some workflow the convenience commands can't reach, use the core commands they execute.

Yeah, git fetch has --depth=1.  I was hoping for a blobless clone, --filter=blob:none, but that may be all I can get.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Fetch is what does the filtering, clone just passes it along to the fetch it runs, if you're going for dead minimum storage try --filter=tree:0 instead of --filter=blob:none... and I see --filter being a fetch option is actually not documented.  Yow.

... ah. I kinda see how that happened, the --filter gets passed along internally to a git rev-list run on the server, by the git upload-pack that runs there to build the pack git fetch came for, so the passthru docs got overlooked by all the people who already knew it had to be passed through and you got left out. Ouch.

Interesting.  I don't see --filter with --help but do see it listed with -h.  That does open up some possibilities.  I'm able to do the "blobless fetch" but can't seem to switch to the tag:  fatal: '--detach' cannot be used with '-b/-B/--orphan'.  That's from git switch --detach my/tag/having/the/same/name/as/a/branch.

git only attaches to branch tips, no need for the option with a tag. Seems petty of it to reject the explicit option when it was going to do that anyway though.

I don't understand "only attaches to branch tips".  I can use --detach to switch to an arbitrary tag or commit hash, branch tip or not.  Well, I could until this case anyway.  I don't see how this is different.

Then it's just an options-checking glitch on top of all the other rough patches in the crack you fell in to. "attach" means "make HEAD refer", in the standard workflow git commit updates HEAD, when you've got a branch tip checked out the convenience command makes HEAD references really be to the branch tip ref, most commands don't care about the distinction and just use HEAD.

minimal-content clone of a tiny slice of a repo with a punned branch and tag where you want the tag, not the branch, isn't something there's convenience syntax for, you get to do yourself what the clone command would be doing for you if they'd anticipated this. It's not hard to do yourself:
git init reponame; cd reponame
git remote add origin u://r/l
git fetch --depth=1 --filter=tree:0 origin refs/tags/yourtag:refs/tags/yourtag


and now you can do whatever it is you were after doing with a repo holding a single content-free commit.
edit: from comments, this is really about a single-commit fetch for a CI build, you really do want the one commit's content. For that, there's no point bothering with a named remote or filtering.
git init `mktemp -d`; cd $_
git fetch --depth=1 u://r/l tags/yourtag
git checkout FETCH_HEAD


I can make this work.  Thanks.  The purpose is to do a final, formal build of the software, one of the uses often given for partial clones.

okay, for that you don't want the filter, just the depth limiter. No point to the stutterstep if you know you're going back for the content immediately, that just makes the same result take more work.
